# What is the view or thing called that pops up in the photos app when you click the leftmost button at the bottom of the screen on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement this on my app. I want to search for tutorials on this topic but I don't know what its called. Can someone please tell me what its called? Eg. In the photos app in iPhone, when u click on the left most button at the bottom, a screen pops up from the bottom giving you options to either email image, set as wallpaper etc.. So, once again, what is this called? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a `UIActionSheet`. Check out the [UIActionSheet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Basically you create one with the designated initializer `-initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` then send the `-showInView:` message to display it. You'll have to set yourself as it's delegate in order to handle selections made by the user.

Comment: Thanks a ton, This is exactly what I needed ! UIActionSheet! Thanks again

Comment: Hey, also, is there a way to use the same icon?

Comment: The button is a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` as the type.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on IB? else, how can I add this button onto the existing toolbar at the rightmost part? Thanks

Comment: Just drag a UIBarButtonItem to the toolbar and set it's style to `Action`. Items added to toolbars will always align to the left, so use a flexible space object to shove it over to the right.

Comment: Ya, thats exactly what I tried, but the style only shows the options as: Done, bordered, plain!

Answer (score 1):

The button is the 'action' barButtonItem type.

The button then opens a modal sheet. Opened with something like:

```
 [self presentModalViewController:menuViewController animated:YES];
```